# Auto-increment int column BUT also allow manual input? Can't use primary key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2005

Our team is developing a new system for some organization.
We have a `Client` table:

```
Id (PK), int, not null
NoClient, int, not null
```

The organization often refers to the Client by its number `NoClient`. Slowly, clients from the old system will be migrated (manually) to the new system.

`NoClient` should be auto-increment (for new clients | feature of the new system) while allowing manual input (for existing clients) and not cause collisions later.

Visually, from the point of view of the auto-increment column:

```
..., 9998, 9999, (used), 10001, 10002
```

Any idea on how to leverage SQL Server 2005 (or Entity Framework) to solve that problem?

Will likely have to create a seed table and use stored procedures (logic embedded) unless there's a better way to do this...

Comment: Just start the identity for new clients at a number higher than largest existing NoClient.   You can override iden insert with set identity_insert  on.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: From MSDN: Allows explicit values to be inserted into the identity column of a table. I basically need a sequential number generator for the `NoClient` column which is not the identity column.

Comment: Why don;t you want to use identity?

Comment: Id (PK) is the identity column. Also, if a user enters 2147483647 it will break on the next insert. From MSDN: If the value inserted is larger than the current identity value for the table, SQL Server automatically uses the new inserted value as the current identity value.

Comment: @maxbeaudoin You said reserve spots for existing.  That means you have to know the existing.  Really you have an existing customer 2147483647.

Comment: @Blam I do... Can't tell if it's junk yet but it's there. Ran a query on the customer database à-la `MAX(NoClient)`.

Comment: @Blam To answer you question: yes I know the existing numbers. They will migrate the clients one by one IF necessary WHEN necessary. There is no automated migration. That's why we have a field `NoClient` that the user can fill.

Comment: @maxbeaudoin So you know the existing client numbers but for the migration you are letting the customer enter the number?  What if they enter the wrong number?

Comment: @Blam Yes.. The reason why the customer wants to manually migrate clients -at his own pace- is because their data is at least 60% garbage (duplicates, tests, etc). `NoClient` is a reference number. Worst case scenario they will not find the client by its number but by its first and/or last name.

Comment: @maxbeaudoin: Then what if a new client is assigned an auto-generated number before an existing client from the old system with the same number has had the chance to be manually entered into the system? Seems like a recipe for trouble to me. Either you segregate the two key types (new and legacy) into mutually exclusive ranges (like Blam suggested) and avoid collisions, or you use different columns and allow collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not very clear.

Have a bool column active.  Load all existing with the column false.   Then just turn it on when the customer is migrated.

As for finding holes.

```
select min(tb1.PK) + 1 
from table tb1 
left outer join table tb2 
on tb2.pk = tb1.pk + 1 
where tb2.pk is null
```

Comment: How do you suggest I improve the question's clarity?

Comment: If that is not the answer then the question is not clear to me.